# Fitting 5 3D images into deep learning model, 4 of the as feratures while the 5th as label?

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I am new to deep learning and image processing.
I am building a deep learning model for 3D image processing, I have 300 test case each is represenred in a folder contains 5 3D (gray scale) images; the dirictories structure is like follow:

```
training -
|   case1
|         | 3Dimg1
|         | 3Dimg2
|         | 3Dimg3
|         | 3Dimg4
|         | 3Dlabel
|   case2
|         | 3Dimg1
.
.
```

How to fit each 5 images in an array where each 4 images are fetures and the 5th is the label for that 4,  and so on for the total 300 cases.

In such case, what the input shape of both the model and training data should be?

I am using keras for the deeplearning model I have, also I am using Conv3D layers as hidden, and all the images are of the size (240, 240, 155)

Comment: The shape of your inputs will be `(240, 240, 155, 4)`, and the shape of your training set will be `(240, 240, 155, 4, N)`. This is assuming new dimensions are appended instead of prepended, otherwise you will have `(4, 240, 240, 155)` and `(N, 4, 240, 240, 155)` as the input and training data, respectively.

Comment: @pciunkiewicz I have a question based on your comment plz, the shape of the training labels in this case should be `(240, 240, 155, N)` as it has always a single image for each case right?